# Excel_VBA - Print frm lower limit to upper limit with step size

Tags: vba, excel

I want to print from cell A2 to A (end of Upper Limit) with step size 0.5. My lower limit can be 0 or 0.5. How can I do it in Excel VBA? for E.g. Lower limit =0 and Upper Limit = 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub increase()
Dim i As Double
Range("A2").Activate

For i = 0 To 30 Step 0.5
    ActiveCell.Value = i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Nitish, it runs fine till ActiveCell.offset(1,0).Activate. It  allots 0 as a value in cell A2, but once it goes  to Next i, it gives error as " Runtime error :424 ---> Object required". I am new to excel VBA coding. Please suggest.

Comment: could you share your code which giving the error. Because the code works fine with me

Comment: I copied and pasted the above code into entirely a new sheet and it worked fine. Thanks for your support.